# ruby - how to pass on incoming named params to another method in one expression?

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a method:

```
def move_knight(orig_x,orig_y,offset_x,offset_y)
  if valid_knight_move(offset_x,offset_y)
    move('knight',orig_x,orig_y,offset_x,offset_y)
  end
end
```

It works.  I would now like to refactor the call to `move` and pass on those last 4 arguments in one go in the call to `move`, as in

```
move('knight',*args)
```

but I get

```
<NameError: undefined local variable or method `args' for #<ChessGame:0x000...>>
```

All the examples I see have `*args` at in the calling methods params which I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as below :

```
def move_knight(*args)
  if valid_knight_move(*args.last(2))
    move('knight',*args)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the method definition to the following:

```
def move_knight(*args)
  if valid_knight_move(args[2],args[3])
    move('knight',*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 Also a useful approach.  Differs in that positions are specified as fixed with `[2]` and `[3]` rather than `last(2)`.  Will work well for some situations/preferences.  I'm liking Arup's `last(2)` approach for my needs but +1 this answer.